# Ayuda con la estructura de un botón

Tags: android-studio

Comencé hace muy poco y tengo un problema del cual no se salir.

Quiero que al presionar un botón aparezca el numero `3` dentro de un `textview`, y que luego, por más que lo presione otra vez no siga apareciendo ya que el `textview` esta limitado a un solo dígito.

Ahora bien, cuando el siguiente `textview` tenga un entero producto de un resultado, al presionar el botón, aparezca el `3` en el siguiente y que se respete el orden:

```
public void BotonTres (View view) {

    if(!et_cocienteuno.equals("")) {
        et_cocienteuno.setText(et_cocienteuno.getText() + "3");
        cociente1 = Integer.parseInt(et_cocienteuno.getText().toString());
    } else
        if(!et_resto2.equals("")) {
        et_cocientedos.setText(et_cocientedos.getText() + "3");
        cociente2 = Integer.parseInt(et_cocientedos.getText().toString());
    } else
        if(!et_resto5.equals("")) {
        et_cocientetres.setText(et_cocientetres.getText() + "3");
        cociente3 = Integer.parseInt(et_cocientetres.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo del todo que es exactamente lo que necesitas. Pero hay dos errores muy comunes: nos olvidamos de poner `.getText()` dentro del **condicional**. Fíjate que estás comparando con el objeto en "si", no del atributo "texto" del propio objeto. También puedes evitar la comparación con un string `""`, si pones `isEmpty`.

Luego si estás limitando la vista a un sólo dígito, no entiendo porque pones:

```
et_cocienteuno.setText(et_cocienteuno.getText() + "3")
```

Quizás deberías poner directamente:

```
et_cocienteuno.setText("3")
```

Luego el 2ndo error consiste en la sintaxis de los condicionales. Los condicionales sólo pueden tener un else, que es el último caso que se ejecuta si las demás condiciones no se cumplen.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
public void BotonTres (View view) {

    if (!et_cocienteuno.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

        et_cocienteuno.setText("3");
        cociente1 = Integer.parseInt(et_cocienteuno.getText().toString());

    } else if (!et_resto2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

        et_cocientedos.setText("3");
        cociente2 = Integer.parseInt(et_cocientedos.getText().toString());

    } else if (!et_resto5.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

        et_cocientetres.setText("3");
        cociente3 = Integer.parseInt(et_cocientetres.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Luego comentas que "se respete el orden": en teoría por los condicionales bien implementados, se debería respetar el orden.

Como me falta información no puedo saber si va por el bien camino, pero por lo menos los errores de sintaxis están arreglados.